# Semantics of mov widths in x64 and SSE

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, freepascal

Consider the following from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Eevans/cs216/guides/x86.html):

> mov BYTE PTR [ebx], 2 ; Move 2 into the single byte at the address stored in EBX.
>
> mov WORD PTR [ebx], 2 ; Move the 16-bit integer representation of 2 into the 2 bytes starting at the address in EBX.
>
> mov DWORD PTR [ebx], 2        ; Move the 32-bit integer representation of 2 into the 4 bytes starting at the address in EBX.

Clearly, we are defining the width of data to move.

Now consider this:

```
movdqu        qword ptr [rcx], xmm0
```

This is moving 128 bits, but we don't write `movdqu dqword`. In fact, `movdqu dword ptr` produces the same results.

Why do the semantics change with the SSE op?

Comment: The assembler doesn't need any help determining the size, just delete qword ptr completely.

Comment: Ok, so it's purely to help the compiler, which is clearly not needed here. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MASM(32 bit, but however) these two lines are rejected as an error.

```
movdqu        qword ptr [ecx], xmm0
movdqu        [ecx], xmm0             
...
test.asm(121) : error A2022:instruction operands must be the same size
```

These two are accepted:

```
movdqu oword ptr [ecx], xmm0    ; explicit 128bit
movdqu xmmword ptr [ecx], xmm0  ; explicit 128bit
```

So the prefix is neccessary and the size prefix matches the 16 bytes=128 bit size of the xmm register. There are two other instructions similar to MOVZX, 32 bit and 64 bit:

```
movd [ecx], xmm0            
movd dword ptr [ecx], xmm0  ; explicit DWORD
movq qword ptr [ecx], xmm0  ; explicit QWORD needed
```

So I couldn't confirm an inconsequency in semantics - at least with MASM.

Comment: What do you mean "standard prefix DWORD"?   Are you saying there's an implicit `dword ptr` and that `movdqu [ecx], xmm0` won't assemble?  It's fine in other assemblers.  If instead of `[ecx]`, you'd used `[varname]`, then I'd guess there might be a problem if you had `varname dd 4 dup(0)` or something that implied a specific size.  `movdqu  qword ptr [ecx], xmm0` is of course rejected, for the mismatch between 64 and 128 bit sizes.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I removed these extra comments. This post is several years old, I can't recall what I meant by this.

Comment: Are you sure `movdqu  [ecx], xmm0` is actually rejected by MASM, though?  That would be very odd to me, because I don't know what would conflict with what.  The only things implying any size at all are XMM0 and the mnemonic, both implying 16-byte with no specific element size.

Comment: `jwasm -win64 foo.asm` or `-pe` accepts `movdqu [ecx], xmm0` without complaint.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Currently I have no assembler ready to test again, so I can't check. Back then I started my answer with "MASM(32 bit, but however)...". This may have been the reason I started with "standard prefix DWORD". And maybe this behavior  changed in the 64-bit version.

Comment: `jwasm -pe` assembles in 32-bit mode; it assembled fine there, too.  It's possible some MASM version might reject it, but I'd hope not.

Answer (score 0):

While indeed in this case the assembler can figure out the operation size, it should nevertheless provide at least a warning if you use a size specification that conflicts with the instruction. You have forgotten to mention which assembler you use, but both nasm and gas provide such diagnostics:

```
nasm: error: impossible combination of address sizes
gas: Error: operand size mismatch for `movdqu'
```

Comment: I'm using Free Pascal, which doesn't give a warning. However, I was asking the meaning behind the sizes, which Hans answered laconically.